# How can I run threads in the background without saying incompatible type?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I can't figure out a way to run the threads in the background without causing incompatible type.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
            HashSet<Thread> threads = new HashSet<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                threads.add(new C());
                threads.add(new H());
                threads.add(new H());
                threads.add(new O());
            }
            // run all threads in background
            for(C carbon : threads){
                carbon.start();
            }
    
            // after all of them are started, wait each of them to finish for maximum 2_000 ms
    
            // for each thread, terminate it if it is not finished
            System.out.println("Possible deadlock!");
            System.out.println("Process finished.");
    
        }
```

Comment: What is the relationship between `C`, `H`, and `O`?

Comment: C, H and O are classes, they represent the elements Carbon, Hydrogen and Oxygen. The program is making vinegar.

Comment: They all extend "Thread`, right?

Comment: Yes. They all are static classes and children of public class Vinegar.

Comment: Then use `Vinegar` type in your for-each loop.

Comment: I think you need change:
```java
for(C carbon : threads){
```
to
```java
for(Thread carbon : threads){
```